# How to create nodes and links of over 1000 dynamically through code in D3

Tags: d3.js

I am working on a project involving force layouts in D3,for which I have to create my sample data with over 1000 nodes that may or may not be linked to each other. I find it tedious to create the links manually in a cvs or excel. Is there any way that I can create the links through a code and also use it in the project where the user can create new links or add new nodes. I have gone through several examples, but I feel I am missing something. Some guidance on this would be great.

Thanks & Regards,
Keerthika.K

Comment: Yes, in principle you can create the links in code -- how to do this depends entirely on what determines whether two nodes should be connected.

Comment: Thanks, I have currently created cvs files with nodes and links, so form here on to work on the dynamic additions and removal of the nodes and links should I convert the csv to json, or is it possible to work with csv, as it is?

Comment: You can work with CSVs.

Comment: Thanks, I will be on it, and post some more questions if any.